# Pandas Data frame Filter Rows of Based on date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter rows based on date column of the pandas' data frame. I've stored last year and last month in variable now wanted to filter rows based on that year and month.

Here is the data frame.
[image]

The Year and month I've stored in below variables.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_month = now.month - 1 if now.month > 1 else 12
last_year = now.year - 1
```

How can I filter rows which contain last_year and last_month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and 
[`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
df[(df['Date'].dt.year == last_year) & (df['Date'].dt.month == last_month)]
```