# Drop certain rows in Pands

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset (csv) with the column attribute date and the format of the attribute like this:

```
2019-10-18 00:00:00+00:00
```

Let's say I want to drop from the dataset all the rows for the years 2019 and 2020 and use the remaining for my model

How would I do that based on that format?
I have tried something like this but I don't think it works...

```
index_names = dataset[ dataset['date'] == 2019 ].index
dataset.drop(index_names, inplace = True)
```

Comment: `newData = dataset[(dataset['date'].dt.year != 2019) | (dataset['date'].dt.year != 2020)].copy()`

Comment: ```index_names = dataset.loc[dataset['date'].str.contains(f'^2019', case = False)]```

Comment: What's the output of  `dataset['date']` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Data frame Filter Rows of Based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034503/pandas-data-frame-filter-rows-of-based-on-date)

Comment: Does date is in a dateformat or string ?

Comment: date is in the exact format i have on the question,not a string,thats why i am struggling

Comment: also replying to chris,the whole date attribute is like that,containing year day month and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.drop(df.loc['startdatetime': 'endatetime'].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.str.contains('^2019')` to fetch all records with 2019, and add `.astype(str)` if the date is in a non-string format

```py
index_names = dataset[ dataset['date'].astype(str).str.contains(f'^2019', case = False)].index
dataset.drop(index_names, inplace = True)
```